# getting data from couchdb in angular js

Tags: angularjs, couchdb

I am using angular js in my employee management app. I am able to produce a JSON from couchdb as shown :

```
[

{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Henry",
    "address": "HSR"
},
{
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Erik",
    "address": "Kormangala"
}
```

]

I can even see the JSON loaded in the NET panel of Firebug.
Here are my angular JS files :
Employee_Manager_App.js:

```
var EMApp= angular.module('EMApp', ['employeeProvider']).config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: '../EMApp/resources/html/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/home",{
        templateUrl : '../EMApp/resources/html/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/' });
});
EMApp.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location){
   $scope.login = function(){
      if($scope.credentials.username === "admin" && $scope.credentials.password === "1234")
        $location.path('/home');
      else
          alert("Username should be admin & Password should be 1234");
   };});
EMApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope, Employees){
$scope.employeeRes = Employees.query();
console.log($scope.employeeRes);});
```

employee_provider.js :

```
angular.module('employeeProvider',['ngResource']).
factory('Employees', function($resource){
    var Employees = $resource('http://localhost\\:5984/myapp/_design/mydesign/_show/employee_shows/9351c38f9a64fd26e40b2ac4cf012efe?name=:value', {value : "employees"}, {query : {method : 'JSONP'}});
    return Employees;
});
```

Even if I could see the JSONs coming as response, there were no employee details seen on the html page where I am using 'employeeRes'.

Does anyone see anything wrong? Please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `$resource`, you're overwriting the default `query` action with your own, but not telling it that the results are expected to come in an array.

I'm guessing you're not seeing the results because you're trying to iterate over them with an ng-repeat.

Try adding the `isArray` flag:

```
var Employeees = $resource(
  url, 
  {value: 'employees'},
  {query: {method: 'JSONP', isArray: true}}
);
```

Comment: hi satchmorun, you guessed it right.I have tried what you suggested. But still it didn't worked.

Comment: to let CouchDB handle JSONP, you need to enable it first by setting `allow_jsonp` option value to `true` under `httpd` config section.